# get keyboard to open underneath Parent view of Edit Text

Tags: android

I do set resize in my manifest so the screen does move up when I tap on the EditText, however It looks like this:

[image]

And I would like it to look like this:

[image]

```
               <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/white_three"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/enter_bio"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_height="130dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                            android:paddingRight="16dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp">


                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/user_biography"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:hint="@string/biography_placeholder"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Font.Volkswagen"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_87"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:maxLength="160"
                                android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoFullscreen"
                                android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/user_biography_counter"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Font.Volkswagen"
                                android:textColor="@color/black_87"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                tools:text="60" />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
```

enter_bio is the element I would like the keyboard to appear under

Answer (score 0):

put the entire view inside a ScrollView and set the android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustPan it will do the trick.
you just need to add this piece of code.

or

Try this

getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

However, instead of doing this at runtime, you can set it in the manifest as an Activity (parent) attribute. This will also be handled in your fragment (child):
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: Getting the error "ScrollView can host only one direct child" sadly I have several in the code I posted above - potentially it's bvecause my entire layout is already in  scroll view - I'm unsure if putting a scroll view on just this view is a good idea - I don't see what purpose it would serve.

Comment: once try this 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" in your manifest  or in your acitivity class getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

Comment: defiantly does not work, sorry. My entire activity is in a scroll view, and I've tried Pan and resize etc. Neither seems to work oddly.